# ROS Kinetic: No script named 'rosdep' although it is installed

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu-16.04, ros

I have a problem using ROS Kinetic in Ubuntu 16.04.
It was working normally but suddenly rosdep dissapeared while I was trying to configure the Turtlebot Simulator and the AR Drone Autonomy Package. 
When I type `sudo rosdep init` it shows the next error

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "/usr/local/bin/rosdep", line 4, in <module>
__import__('pkg_resources').run_script('rosdep==0.11.5', 'rosdep')
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 739,in run_script
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1486, in run_script
pkg_resources.ResolutionError: No script named 'rosdep'
```

I tried to install *rosdep* manually with  `sudo apt-get install python-rosdep` but it shows that `python-rosdep is already the newest version (0.11.5-1)`

I tried uninstalling ROS using `sudo apt-get purge ros-*` and `sudo apt-get autoremove` and installing it again.
And also reinstalling it using `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ros-kinetic-desktop-full` but no working.

I am following the instructions of the official 
 [site](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu) . 
Any idea of what can I do to solve this? Thanks

Comment: Did you source the setup.bash? If not run `source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash` and then try again in the same terminal.

Answer (score 1):

rosdep is actually completely independent from all the ros-** packages because it is used to install them, which is why reinstalling those packages didn't help.

My best guess would be that you used pip in addition to apt for something with rosdep, and now have 1.5 or 3 different versions of rosdep. Please try removing rosdep installed using apt completely:
`apt-get purge python-rosdep` and make sure that there are no errors when removing the package. If there are any, post them as comment here. Then, check all python import paths for a folder named `rosdep`, and remove them. You can find out your python import paths by running the following python script:

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

Then, you type `which rosdep`. If there is a rosdep binary anywhere, remove it. Then you can reinstall rosdep: `sudo apt install python-rosdep`.

Comment: Considering that the error said /usr/local, you are quite likely right about a locally installed copy - apparently it is missing somefiles. Deleting /usr/local/bin/rosdep may already help, but checking /usr/local/share for anything `rosdep` and removing it seems sensible.